# Injection error when using Jasmine with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I've been following the example of this developer for how to setup some basic Jasmine tests with AngularJS [here](https://blogs.endjin.com/2014/09/unit-testing-angularjs-with-visual-studio-resharper-and-teamcity/)

My problem seems to be that across my entire app, I am using one module which I refer to as myApp. However in my tests it complains about missing references.

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute', 'ui.router', 'ngResource']);
})();
```

**dogService,js**

```
(function () {
        "use strict";

        var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp');
        myAppModule.factory('Dog', function () {

        var dogs = [
            { type: "Labrador", name: "Rover" },
            { type: "Tibetan Terrier", name: "Joey" },
            { type: "Yorkshire Terrier", name: "Rufus" }
        ];

        return {
            query: function () {
                return dogs;
            },
            add: function (dog) {
                dogs.push(dog);
            }
        };
    });
}());
```

**serviceSpec.js**

```
///<reference path="~/Scripts/jasmine.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/jasmine-html.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/boot.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/angular.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/angular-mocks.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/App/app.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/App/Services/dogService.js"/>
"use strict";
describe("dogService", function () {

    beforeEach(module("myApp"));

    describe("Dog service", function () {

        var dog;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
            dog = $injector.get('Dog');
        }));

        it('should return 3 dogs when querying', function () {
            expect(dog.query().length).toBe(3);
        });

        it('should return 4 dogs when querying after adding a dog', function () {
            dog.add({ name: 'Fido', type: 'German Shepherd' });
            expect(dog.query().length).toBe(4);
        });
    });
});
```

Finally my error:

```
finished in 0.071s2 specs, 2 failuresSpec List | FailuresSpec List | Failures 

dogService Dog service should return 3 dogs when querying

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngAnimate due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngAnimate' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
```

If I change app.js to this, I won't get any errors, however I am going to have to inject dependencies at a top level in the module.

```
(function () {
        "use strict";

        var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
    })();
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Have you installed the ngAnimate dependency?  This isn't included by default in Angular.

Comment: @jazmit I am developing in a .net 4.5 environment so I have a script bundle that includes ngAnimate and it's definitely in the script folder, I have no problems accessing the website, the injection error is only when running the tests.

Comment: But it's not in the list of referenced scripts at the top of your serviceSpec.js file. Same for ngRoute, ngResource and ui.router. BTW, why do you use both ngRoute and ui.router. That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @JBNizet It shouldn't be referencing both, this project is a side-project and I simply forgot to remove it. Is there a more elegant way of referencing all those scripts without having to declare everything above the tests?

Comment: Use [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/index.html)

Comment: @JBNizet Ok I need to investigate using Karma more because I did the basic init to get it up and running but I am also trying to integrate all the technologies nicely into .net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was missing references of the angular files that are injected into myApp.

```
///<reference path="~/Scripts/angular-animate.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/angular-resource.js"/>
```

Adding these fixed it but it's only a work-around solution because it's a lot of references to add for each test script.